# Grammatical error in recommend deletion canned comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

I recently reviewed and recommended deletion of an answer for being a "I'm having this problem too" comment. While the selection menu is fine, I noticed the [canned comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600825/how-to-show-all-hidden-controls-of-a-form-in-c/12244849#comment18291433_12244849) that got posted has a grammatical error:

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different
>   question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a
>   bounty to draw more attention to this question **to this question** once
>   you have enough reputation.

I notice the "once you have enough reputation" bit got cleverly tacked on since the answerer was low-rep. I wonder if the bug is related to that functionality.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't show like that in the actual popup menu to select it. o.o

Comment: Heh... Looks like this has been sitting around for a few months now, unnoticed since it's only posted for users with < 75 points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, nice find.  I have fixed up the delete comment and backfilled all of the existing ones.